# Segmentation fault or Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small)

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, segmentation-fault

```
long keyIntValue;
uint8_t *value; 

sscanf(buffer, " %*[^\"\n]\"%9[^;\"\n]", keyStringValue);
keyIntValue = strtol(keyStringValue, NULL, 16);
*value = *(uint8_t*)keyIntValue;
printf("The value is 0x%x \n", *value);
```

I get segmentation fault for the above code with GCC compiler

```
*(long *)value = keyIntValue;
 printf("The value is 0x%x \n", *(long *)value);
```

The above code works with gcc and gets the correct output but I get Suspicious pointer-to-pointer conversion (area too small) with bitbake compiler

How to solve this?

Comment: How is `keyStringValue` defined?

Comment: why you need `value` to be a pointer?

Comment: @SouravGhosh That's part of interface so I cant change it

Comment: @dasblinkenlight keyStringValue is charb array

Answer (score 3):

```
*value = *(uint8_t*)keyIntValue;
```

Dereferencing uninitialized pointer leads to undefined behavior hence the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to treat a portion of `keyIntValue` as a `uint8_t`, you can do it by taking an address of `keyIntValue`, like this:

```
unsigned char *value;
value = (unsigned char*)(&keyIntValue);
printf("The value is 0x%x \n", *value);
```

**Note:** The reason I changed the type of `value` to a pointer to `unsigned char` is to avoid violating the strict aliasing rule. Pointers to character types are allowed to alias to anything, so changing the type fixes the aliasing problem.

Comment: Doesn't this break `strict aliasing rule`?

Comment: @Gopi You are right, on systems where `uint8_t` is *not* a character type, this would break strict aliasing. I have not seen such systems, though. I'll update with more info.

Comment: I really don't see any reason why we need such code where you have different type pointers pointing to same memory location breaking the strict aliasing rule.. So its better not to have it is what I feel. Yeah in case of char or uint8_t it should be ok but better to suggest not to use it. Also the result depends on endianess ..

Comment: I cant change the type of value because its part of interface. Suggest me better solution with having uint8_t * value...